# Is there an efficiency reason to use the => syntax for getters in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

So, coming from Java, I'm used to writing traditional syntax for Dart. Thus, I have a tendency to write my getters:

```dart
int get foo {
   return 0;
}
```

However, I've found the => syntax, which is more concise:

```dart
int get foo => 0;
```

I can't find what exactly this => syntax does: is it just shorthand, or does it have an efficiency boost? If it's the latter, then I will port my current projects to using it; otherwise, I will just follow the convention in the future. (I can't provide a specific example, due to some strict regulations on sharing code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That fat arrow `=>` syntax is just a short hand for returning an expression and is similar to,

```
int getSomething () { 
   return something; 
}
```

you can find about this and more in [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Comment: @AKushWarrior Please accept the answer once your doubt or issue is solved out, someone might get use of it. thanks

Comment: The parentheses after a getter is a syntax error in Dart. This code would not compile.

Comment: Sorry about the late acceptance, there is a time limit before you can accept.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Dart Language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions):

> The `=> expr` syntax is a shorthand for `{ return expr; }`.

There isn't a performance improvement from using one or the other, arrow functions are just more concise and (in my opinion) quite often easier to read.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I presumed, but I wasn't sure. I'll make sure to use it in future projects.